# Excel VBA help needed

Tags: excel, vba

How to do this using VBA?
Column A has multiple cells with numeric values.
The number of cells in column A is dynamic.
The numeric value is a 16 digit number.
Ex. 1234567891234567
I need to split this numeric value as below:
Delete first two numbers and keep only next 4 digits and delete all other numbers.
Expected output: 3456
This 3456 shd populate in column B

So, to summarize the user fills column A with numeric values.
And runs the macro.
The 4 digits numeric values shd get displayed In Column B.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  If you post your current code within the question, we can possibly help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code would do the work:

```
Sub GetDigits()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 1).Value, 3, 4)
    Next i
End Sub
```